# Graph,Text and Analytics combined search

Tags: elasticsearch, database-design, neo4j, graph-databases, bigdata

So i'm building a system, which has Persons,Bank Accounts and Bank Account transactions.
I need to be able to answer questions such as:
"return all people connected from 1/2/3 degree to a specific person",
"return all people which their age is > 40"
"return transactions from bank branches in Germany"
and also combined queries such as
"return all people connected to specific person OR persons living in London"

I also need to provide several analytics queries.

When trying to modeling the problem, I thought using both Neo4j & Elasticsearch.
I'll save all the data in Elasticsearch (index per type), and the relations (person->person and person->bank account) I will store in neo4j.

My only issue now is how to combine queries from both data stores together.
In the moment i need to pass results from one database to another to query a smaller subset, i need to use Ids, so I actually need to wait until all the query is done.
for example, query like:
"return all people connected to specific person AND living in London"
I will need to go to Elasticsearch and ask for all people living in London - I might get here millions of ids, which I need to pass to neo4j now, and create a cypher on those ids.
So i can't use this method - is there a recommendation for doing such a thing? I tried also looking for a neo4j-Elasticsearch plugin but the one i found was not so good...

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just use neo4j alone?

Comment: Full text search,  Geo search,  a lot of aggregations and analytics..

Comment: In case you were not aware, neo4j also supports [full-text search](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/fulltext-search-in-neo4j/) and [a plugin for geospatial search](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial).

Comment: I know, but I need very wide support, such as special analyzers, tokenizers and many other things that i'm gettinf from Elastic out of the box.

Comment: You may want to elaborate on how complex your text based queries can get. Given your examples, if you're also modeling cities/countries/locations in Neo4j, it's easy to do a lookup on a city with CONTAINS or STARTS WITH, and from there match up on places or people related to the city.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to avoid using 2 different DBs to perform a single query, as it adds complexity, overhead, and latency. Instead, perhaps you can write all the data into a neo4j DB and [push to ElasticSearch](https://neo4j.com/developer/elastic-search/#_push_to_elasticsearch) just the data that you need to use with ElasticSearch. If this is acceptable, then all your read-only queries would use just one DB -- the one most appropriate for the query.

Comment: Do you think neo has all the features to perform searches such as the one i'm getting from Elasticsearch?

Comment: Maybe, but I cannot say for sure without a lot more info.